# Angular 2 (RC) Testing Systemjs "Require is not defined"

Tags: angular, requirejs, karma-jasmine

I am trying to get unit testing with coverage working on an application that I'm working on. I have followed various guides explaining how to set this up but I'm stuck on a console error that says "Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined"

I did some research and it sounds like require should be defined by systemjs which I am including, so I'm not sure why require is still undefined. I'm guessing that require was moved to some other file besides system.src.js for RC1. There is no documentation for doing this beyond beta which isn't helping :(

There were two files I see referenced in documentation online that existed in beta and are missing in RC. These are angular2.dev.js and testing.dev.js. I have not found any replacement for angular2.dev.js so I'm just hoping it's in zone or reflectMetadata... As far as testing.dev.js the closest thing I can find is @angular/core/testing/testing.js but I really have no idea if that's the right file or not.

Here's my karma.confif.js file:

```
module.exports = function(config) {
    config.set({

        basePath: '.',

        frameworks: ['jasmine'],

        files: [
            // paths loaded by Karma
            {
              pattern: 'node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js',
              included: true,
              watched: true
            }, {
              pattern: 'node_modules/reflect-metadata/Reflect.js',
              included: true,
              watched: true
            }, {
              pattern: 'node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js',
              included: true,
              watched: true
            }, {
              pattern: 'node_modules/rxjs/bundles/Rx.js',
              included: true,
              watched: true
            }, {
              pattern: 'node_modules/@angular/core/testing/testing.js',
              included: true,
              watched: true
            }, {
              pattern: 'karma-test-shim.js',
              included: true,
              watched: true
            },

            // paths loaded via module imports
            {
              pattern: 'dist/**/*.js',
              included: false,
              watched: true
            },

            // paths to support debugging with source maps in dev tools
            {
              pattern: 'src/**/*.ts',
              included: false,
              watched: false
            }, {
              pattern: 'dist/**/*.js.map',
              included: false,
              watched: false
            }
        ],

        // proxied base paths
        proxies: {
            // required for component assests fetched by Angular's compiler
            '/src/': '/base/src/'
        },

        port: 9876,

        logLevel: config.LOG_INFO,

        colors: true,

        autoWatch: true,

        browsers: ['Chrome'],

        // Karma plugins loaded
        plugins: [
            'karma-jasmine',
            'karma-coverage',
            'karma-chrome-launcher'
        ],

        // Coverage reporter generates the coverage
        reporters: ['progress', 'dots', 'coverage'],

        // Source files that you wanna generate coverage for.
        // Do not include tests or libraries (these files will be instrumented by Istanbul)
        preprocessors: {
            'dist/**/!(*spec).js': ['coverage']
        },

        coverageReporter: {
            reporters:[
                {type: 'json', subdir: '.', file: 'coverage-final.json'}
            ]
        },

        singleRun: true
    })
};
```

Here's my karam-test-shim.js file:

```
// Tun on full stack traces in errors to help debugging
Error.stackTraceLimit = Infinity;

jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL = 1000;

// // Cancel Karma's synchronous start,
// // we will call `__karma__.start()` later, once all the specs are loaded.
__karma__.loaded = function() {};

System.config({
    packages: {
        'base/dist': {
            defaultExtension: false,
            format: 'cjs',
            map: Object.keys(window.__karma__.files).filter(onlyAppFiles).reduce(createPathRecords, {})
        }
    }
});

System.import('angular2/src/platform/browser/browser_adapter')
    .then(function(browser_adapter) { browser_adapter.BrowserDomAdapter.makeCurrent(); })
    .then(function() { return Promise.all(resolveTestFiles()); })
    .then(function() { __karma__.start(); }, function(error) { __karma__.error(error.stack || error); });

function createPathRecords(pathsMapping, appPath) {
    // creates local module name mapping to global path with karma's fingerprint in path, e.g.:
    // './vg-player/vg-player':
    // '/base/dist/vg-player/vg-player.js?f4523daf879cfb7310ef6242682ccf10b2041b3e'
    var pathParts = appPath.split('/');
    var moduleName = './' + pathParts.slice(Math.max(pathParts.length - 2, 1)).join('/');
    moduleName = moduleName.replace(/\.js$/, '');
    pathsMapping[moduleName] = appPath + '?' + window.__karma__.files[appPath];
    return pathsMapping;
}

function onlyAppFiles(filePath) {
    return /\/base\/dist\/(?!.*\.spec\.js$).*\.js$/.test(filePath);
}

function onlySpecFiles(path) {
    return /\.spec\.js$/.test(path);
}

function resolveTestFiles() {
    return Object.keys(window.__karma__.files)  // All files served by Karma.
        .filter(onlySpecFiles)
        .map(function(moduleName) {
            // loads all spec files via their global module names (e.g.
            // 'base/dist/vg-player/vg-player.spec')
            return System.import(moduleName);
        });
}
```